# disable button in ascx page prior to postback

Tags: asp.net

How do I disable a button in an ascx page?  I know how to do it on an aspx page with:

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
  "this.disabled=true;this.value='Please Wait...';needToConfirm=false;" +
  ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, "").ToString());
```

But the ClientScript function is not present in the ascx page.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the ClientScript in code behind, you can also have it directly in the button tag as `OnClientClick` attribute:

```
<asp:Button id="btnSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait...'; needToConfirm=false;" Text="Save" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the ClientScript property using `Page.ClientScript` from your user control (ascx).

Answer (score 1):

you can access ClientScript through the Page property of your control

```
Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed the problem.  In every page, I have three divs:

```
<div align="center" id="divWait" style="display:none"><asp:Label ID="lblSaveorCancel" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>

<div style="display:block" id="divMain">

----  page actual content here  ------

</divMain>

<div id="divBut" style="text-align:center;display:block">
<asp:button id="SaveBtn" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return Validate('save');"/>
<asp:button id="CancelBtn" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="return ShowWaitDiv('cancel');"/>
</div>
```

And then I added scripts:

```
function Validate(saveorcancel) {

-----  validation checks for data on the page  ------

}

function ShowWaitDiv(saveorcancel) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divWait.id);
    div.style.display = "block";
    var div1 = document.getElementById(divMain.id);
    div1.style.display = "none";
    var div2 = document.getElementById(divBut.id);
    div2.style.display = "none";
    if (saveorcancel == 'save') {
        document.getElementById('<%= lblSaveorCancel.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'Saving data, please wait...';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('<%= lblSaveorCancel.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'Redirecting, please wait...';
    }
    return true;
}
```

Simple, quick, and the user sees the result of clicking a button immediately and cannot click any buttons again.